# Encoding issue with URLConnection URL containing accented characters

Tags: java, android, encoding, urlconnection

I am using URLConnection to connect with my Apache server to download files.

If I use this url : http://myserver.com/files/ete.ext    - it works however if I make
http://myserver.com/files/été.ext it doesn't work.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while working with the google maps API. Certain places had accented characters and it didn't work properly. My workaround (it is probably pretty sloppy) was to simply replace all of the accented characters with non-accented ones.

I simply called the replaceAll function for all of my strings and got rid of all of the invalid characters.

I hope this helps

Comment: This will not help if the server actually has a file named such (and we want to retrieve this file).

Comment: this didnt help because the filename was changed when I changed those charachters

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
$address = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $address);
```

I hope this will be helpful, if iconv extension is available